# loop through a dictionary list and 1) compare a flow value to the flow column element 2) if it matches then append a new list with data

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
Sensor_Data_df={"Sensor" :[2306,2305,2304,2303,2302 ], "Time" :   [3.06,5.17,6.89,6.83,6.83], "Flow": [60,69,66,104,60]}
```

I need to loop through a list and compare a flow value to the flow column element and if it matches then append to a new list with the sensor data. There are several thousands of rows of data but only 127 flows. So it seems like a nested loop seems to fit but I'm new to pandas and Python.

Objective is to create a new dictionary list as follows:

```
flows_df={"60":[2306,2302],"66":[2304],"69":[2305],"104":[2303]}
```

I need something like this but haven't been able to get the if statement so I can compare a value:

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})
print(dfc)

numrows=len(dfc.loc[:,'A'])

print("The number of elements is " + str(numrows))

z_list=[]
ilist=[0,1,2]
i=0
for i in range(len(dfc['A'])):
#   if dfc[i,'A']==ilist.value()

z_list.append(dfc.loc[:,'B'])

print("____")
print(z_list)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your desired output for a given output? As it stands, it is hard to see how `dfc` relates to `Sensor_Data_df`, and from your description, it is not clear what would be the expected results when you provide an element corresponding to more than one value of `Flow` (which would be 60 for your given example).

Answer (score 2):

If you let `df = pd.DataFrame(Sensor_Data_df)`, then you could do

```
df.groupby('Flow').Sensor.apply(list).to_dict()
```

For your example data:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]:
   Sensor  Time  Flow
0    2306  3.06    60
1    2305  5.17    69
2    2304  6.89    66
3    2303  6.83   104
4    2302  6.83    60

In [165]: df.groupby('Flow').Sensor.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[165]: {60: [2306, 2302], 66: [2304], 69: [2305], 104: [2303]}
```

A pure Python solution that would probably also fit the size of your data (unless part of a tight loop) and save you the dependency on pandas would be

```
from collections import defaultdict

sensors_by_flow = defaultdict(list)
for flow, sensor in zip(Sensor_Data_df['Flow'], Sensor_Data_df['Sensor']):
    sensors_by_flow[flow].append(sensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the DataFrame (which is inefficient and generally should be avoided when working with pandas) you can test what flows are in `ilist` by using [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on your flow column.

In your example the relevant values in column `A` can be extracted like this:

```
dfc.loc[dfc['B'].isin(ilist), 'A']
```